# Ctrl-C is ignored by pppd when put in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, point-to-point-protocol, signals

I'm trying to connect to GPRS network through a serial port connected GSM modem.

When I call `/usr/sbin/pppd call <peer_name>` from the command line, It correctly receives and handles <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from keyboard. But when I put the exact same command in an empty shell script (with or without the shebang at the top), `chmod +x` it and run it from the shell prompt, `pppd` starts to run but it totally ignores <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> key combination. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> works normally though.

This is the contents of the pppd peer file

```
nodetach
dump
connect "connect_script"
disconnect "disconnect_script"
/dev/ttyS0
noauth
```

I tested another peer file which I had created to connect to a PPTP VPN server, with the same result. PPTP does not need a chat script, so I'm ruling out problems with `chat` command or serial port link properties.

OS is debian 7.

Any ideas what is happening here?

Comment: Try having the shell for the script run as interactive `#!/bin/bash -i`.

Comment: `bash -i` didn't help. Can someone reproduce and confirm this problem on their machine? On my machine this problem only applies to `pppd`. As far as I checked, no other program has this issue.